# How can I make multiple projects share node_modules directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I have been following many react tutorials(just getting started). In all of them, node modules are locally installed within each project. But I don't want to download node modules all the time for each project. I want to install node modules globally, which reside in the following location in windows (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules), and then refer them for all of my react projects.
Whenever I do projects, I have to download all dependencies of node modules. Without copying the node_modules, Is there any way to share the central node_modules in multiple projects?

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea in general... but you can use yarn workspaces. But you're going to have to make sure you use the same version of all the packages in different workspaces.

Comment: why is not a good idea

Comment: Because different project will likely need different packages. Which cascades to all the dependencies of the packages ect. It get's really messy very fast to try and have a big `node_modules` with everything in it. It will also break if you get uncompatible versions of dependencies in there.